# Apple Time Capsule won't extend wireless network

Tags: network, wifi, airport, time-capsule

I am running a Wifi network with a fritzbox 7360 and all my apple devices (apple tv old and new, MacbookPro, mac mini, iPhone, iPad) can connect just fine. Recently I bought apple time capsule 3TB which won't join my local wifi for unknown reasons. I ran several resets, checked configuration and read all I could found on the internet. Connectivity and placement seems fine as well (I checked with other devices).

Below are my settings. Can somebody help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my Time Capsule extend my wireless network?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98738/why-wont-my-time-capsule-extend-my-wireless-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining and extending WiFi networks is only supported with Apple devices. The TC won't join your fritzbox WiFi. You can cable it in however and it'll function as a backup device.

Comment: Not entirely true. I have a Fritzbox 3490 and my (old flat style) 3TB Time Capsule is happy enough to join the network wirelessly as a regular network client. I've been unable to persuade it to *extend* the network, however.

Comment: Good to know. I've never seen an Apple device successfully do that.